# Weird issue with Core Image and Window Resizing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, exc-bad-access, core-image

OK, here's my issue :

- I have an `NSImageView` subclass, onto which the user can drag'n'drop an image (a.k.a. `dropper`)
- Once the image is dropped, a 'processed' version of it is shown in an `NSImageView` next it (a.k.a. `output`)

Pretty straightforward so far.

The thing is, whenever I try resizing the window (**after** showing the processed image), the app crashes (`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`), nothing being showing in the console (no actual error, even though `NSZombieEnabled` is set to on).

---

If I just "copy" the image, the resizing works fine :

```
[_output setImage:[_dropper image]];
```

However, when I set `_output`'s image to the filtered version, there comes the problem :

```
NSImage* processed = [[[_dropper image] copy] filteredWith:[CIFilter sepiaToneWithIntensity:0.5]];

[_output setImage:processed];
```

---

And here are the 2 functions mentioned above (actually, categories I've written for `CIImage` and `CIFilter` respectively) :

```
- (NSImage*)filteredWith:(CIFilter *)filter
{
    NSImage* start = [self copy];

    CIContext* context = [[CIContext alloc] init];

    CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)[start TIFFRepresentation], NULL);
    CGImageRef ref = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(src, 0, NULL);
    CIImage* img = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

    [filter setValue:img forKey:kCIInputImageKey];

    CIImage* result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
    CGImageRef res = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[result extent]];

    NSImage* final = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:res size:[start size]];

    return final;
}

+ (CIFilter*)sepiaToneWithIntensity:(CGFloat)intensity
{
    CIFilter* newFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepiaTone"];
    [newFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:intensity] forKey:@"inputIntensity"];

    return newFilter;
}
```

---

Any ideas?

Comment: FWIW, I wrote a small application to test your code and it works. I’m wondering whether `-[CIContext init]` is reliable since it doesn’t receive a `CGContextRef`; on the other hand, the resulting `NSImage` does seem to work. Also, apparently you are not using ARC (which complains about the non-bridged `CFDataRef` cast), so `-filteredWith:` is leaking a few objects.

Comment: @Bavarious Wow, thanks a lot for the try, buddy! Well, I'm not using ARC **and** the `NSImage` does seem to be working. However, 2 hours later, I still can't figure this one out. Any suggestions?